# why validation is parallel to test and train line in a RMSE curve?

Tags: validation, rms

I just make a CNN model and then draw a curve for RMSE. the result is according to below. why validation line don't reach to train and test line? but in R2 curve they all reach together! do my model has a good performance or not?[image]

[image]

Comment: If you would zoom more into the R2 plot, you would probably see the same behavior. These numbers will never fully agree and different plots will make it look like they are close together or far apart.